# printing a linked list in c

Tags: c, list, struct

I have to make for homework 2 linked lists, put integers given from the user in the first and then put the result=x^3 for each integer of the first to the second list. In the following code, I am trying to print what I put in the first list, reading with scanf. I haven't yet understood why can't I print by this way. Could you please explain? Thanks in advance!! The problem is that I print only the last element and 0... :s

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct L1 
{
    int x;
    struct L1 *next1;
};

struct L2 
{
    int x,i,v;
    struct L2 *next2;
};

int main()
{
    int i,N;
    struct L1 *root1; 
    struct L2 *root2;
    struct L1 *conductor1;  
    struct L2 *conductor2;

    root1 = malloc(sizeof(struct L1));  
    root2 = malloc(sizeof(struct L2));
    root1->next1=0;
    conductor1 = root1;
    printf("Dwste arithmo N");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("\nDwse arithmo");
    scanf("%d",&conductor1->x);
    printf("%d",conductor1->x);

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        conductor1->next1 = malloc(sizeof(struct L1));
        printf("\nDwste arithmo");
        scanf("%d",&conductor1->x);
        conductor1->next1=0;
    }
    conductor1 = root1;
    while (conductor1 != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%d",conductor1->x);
        conductor1=conductor1->next1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what problem are you experiencing?  Won't compile, crash, error message?

Comment: yeah I edited it xD sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `for` loop you are never changing the value of `conductor1`. So it will always point to the head node, and you will always overwrite the fields of that node. You need to add `conductor1=conductor1->next1;` after allocating the new node to advance to the next node in each iteration.

Comment: change it like that you mean? conductor1=conductor1->next1;

Comment: @alex777: Yes, after the `malloc`.